# iOS UITableViewController cells jumping out of place after resizing cell heights on first change

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, uicontainerview

Update: It looks like the `tableView.estimatedRowHeight` setting is somehow related to the problem, since the variance of the problem changes as the number changes, and setting it to 9999 makes it "go away" but that seems super hacky. The 9999 also breaks the animations I intended to do on the show/hide. 9999 also breaks the scrollbars funtionality.  See the discussion thread below for additional details and full context.

I have a view controller which holds two `Container Views`. Each container view holds a `UITableView` controller.  They're orientated vertically each taking up the full height.

The container on the right side has a width of 100 and starts off screen with the trailing constraint set to -100 which allows the other container to fill the whole screen initially.

The table on the left has automatic adjusting cell heights using `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` since when the hidden view is shown, some text on two lines may need to wrap to the next line.

When I change the constraint to be 0 and show the view, if I'm not at the top of the list, rather than expanding what's visible on the screen, it seems to be expanding everything, thus pushing what was on the screen down, further than it should be going.

What's weird though, is subsequent expand/collapses work as expected, only adjusting what is visible.

I've attached a video a video showing the issue, I'm just trying to connect things up and get the sizing working right now, the content in the right view will be different eventually.

The following is what's happening in the video

1. I expand/collapse from the top of the list and it works as expected
2. I scroll to middle of list, and expand, and my content gets pushed down further than it should be.
3. I then collapse and expand it again, and this time it stays in place since no sizes changed on the visible screen.

It doesn't matter how far down the list I go, the same behaviour happens, getting worse as I go further down.

[image]

I'm adjusting the constraints like this on a button press for now.

```
   if self.timeContainerConstraint.constant == 0 {
        self.timeContainerConstraint.constant = -90.0
   } else {
        self.timeContainerConstraint.constant = 0.0
   }
```

Does anyone know why the content is jumping when I scroll down the list and expand the first time, but not jumping on subsequent attempts?

Comment: Have you implemented `estimatedHeightForRowAt:` ?

Comment: No, but I've set the estimatedRowHeight

tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 140

Comment: Do you call `layoutIfNeeded` on the container after changing the constraint?

Comment: I've tried it with and without and it's behaving the same way.  I've also tried using it on the tableView inside the containerView.  It all behaves the same.

Comment: What constraints have you set?  Have you tried debugging the view hierarchy to see what the size of the container is when it is "off screen"?  It looks like the top/bottom isn't being set correctly initially when off screen.  Do you add the constraints through storyboard or code?  Do you get any constraint warnings in the console?  Is the container inside or outside the table view & cells?

Comment: It's all being done through the storyboard.  Here's an image of what it looks like, I tried to show all the appropriate parts http://imgur.com/a/lzZq2  You can see it off screen on the right, it's showing it as the three lines.  I just checked the view hierarchy, it doesn't show it when it's off scree, but it looks okay on screen.   The container is holding the tableview and it's cells.  If it was a top/bottom issue, I would expect the sudden change to be consistent, but it gets worse the further down the list I go.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138783/discussion-between-paulw11-and-ben987654).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As you have variable cell heights, the tableview can't correctly calculate the scroll offset when its frame changes.  It has to rely on the estimated row height, but as you have a fixed value for this, the more cells 'above' the current scroll position, the greater the error between the estimated and the actual value.

I was able to solve this by caching the cell heights in order to return a more accurate estimated height using `estimatedHeightForRowAt:`

```
var cellHeights = [IndexPath:CGFloat]()

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let frame = tableView.rectForRow(at: indexPath)

    self.cellHeights[indexPath] = frame.size.height

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return self.cellHeights[indexPath] ?? 140.0
}
```

Using this approach, the expansion and contraction of the side bar didn't affect the table's position.  I was able to animate the constraint change for a nice smooth reveal and the table didn't 'jump', even if the table was scrolling while the side bar was opened.

My sample project is [here](https://github.com/paulw11/TableDemoThingy)

Comment: Wow, I think this is working perfectly, even solving some other animation stutters I hadn't considered yet. I have to run off to work, but I'll give it a better look when I get home and mark this if things are still good after a little more testing.

Comment: It's working beautifully.  Thank you so much for all your help on this problem!

Comment: Thanks for the tip ! Works like a charm :-)

Comment: This should be built in iOS behavior!